# Unable to get POST or GET form data while using AJAX

Tags: django, django-filter

Have been trying to filter data using django-filters. The code is working when I send a separate POST or GET request from the template. I want to avoid that extra reload that's taking place to filter the table of information.

Here's the view:

```
def search(request):

    dynamic_filter = [f.name for f in Controlpanel._meta.get_fields()]

    class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        class Meta:
            model = Controlpanel
            fields = dynamic_filter

    user_list = Controlpanel.objects.all()
    user_filter = UserFilter(request.GET.get("filters[]"), 
    queryset=user_list)
    chart = list(user_filter.qs.values())

    return JsonResponse(chart, safe=False)
```

Here's the AJAX code that calls this above view:

```
$('#filter-data').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var dynamic = $('#filter-data').serialize();
    console.log($('#filter-data').serializeArray())
    $.ajax({
      url: '/search/',
      type: 'GET',
      data: {
        filters : dynamic
      },
      dataType: 'json',
   success : function(json) {
        console.log(json); // log the returned json to the console
        console.log("success"); // another sanity check
    },

    // handle a non-successful response
    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText); // provide a bit more info about the error to the console
    }
    });
```

The request.GET(or POST) currently stays empty even if I add a CSRF token and make it a POST request.

I came across some question on SO stating that use of request.body solves the issue but even that was a fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the POST request was being passed as a string.

This solved the issue:

```
user_filters = request.POST.get('filters', '')
user_filters = user_filters.split("&")

user_filters = {item.split("=")[0]: item.split("=")[1].replace("%20", " ")
                for item in user_filters}

user_filters.pop('csrfmiddlewaretoken')
```